# ES6 Map.forEach is not a function after typescript compilation

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, ts-loader

I am trying to use the new [collection types of ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) in my typescript/react project.

```
interface MyComponentProps{
  myMap: Map<String, {isAvailable?: boolean}>,
}
...
this.props.myMap.keys();
```

IntelliJ and Webpack can compile my code without warnings, but I got an error at runtime in Chrome 55.
`this.props.myMap.forEach is not a function`

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"moduleResolution": "node",
"outDir": "./dist/",
"sourceMap": true,
"noImplicitAny": true,
"module": "commonjs",
"target": "es6",
"jsx": "react"
  }
}
```

`package.json`

```
{
 "name": "cocktails-db",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
  "production": "webpack -p",
  "start": "webpack-dev-server -d",
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.15.3",
  "elasticsearch": "^12.1.0",
  "react": "^15.4.0",
  "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.7",
  "react-dom": "^15.4.0",
  "react-router": "^3.0.0",
  "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.23.1",
  "react-select2-wrapper": "^1.0.4-beta1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/axios": "^0.9.34",
  "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.32",
  "@types/elasticsearch": "^5.0.1",
  "@types/react": "^0.14.51",
  "@types/react-bootstrap": "0.0.37",
  "@types/react-dom": "^0.14.19",
  "@types/react-router": "^2.0.41",
  "@types/react-router-bootstrap": "0.0.27",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.1",
  "ts-loader": "^1.2.2",
  "typescript": "^2.0.10",
  "webpack": "^1.13.3",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
}
}
```

I still can use the Map type when type in the browser's console, so I guess it's a problem of typescript compilation. 
I am missing a dependency somewhere ?

--- Edit ---
It was actually an initialization problem, but I still don't know why I don't get Typescript feedback/type warning.

This is how I call ´MyComponent´

```
myMap : any;
...
this.myMap="";
...
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyComponent myMap={this.myMap}> </MyComponent>
            </div>
        )
```

Comment: Please add more relevant code.  Are you sure you are passing a map?

Comment: It is expected that ES6 polyfilled features will be polyfilled. And it is obvious that it isn't so in your case.

Comment: @estus there's no need to pollyfill, chrome supports the `Map` object

Comment: @NitzanTomer The question doesn't specify which Chrome version is used, but usually web app clients aren't limited to Chrome. Though it is unlikely that it has Map but doesn't have Map.prototype.forEach.

Comment: @estus It does say chrome 55, which supports `Map`. It might be another problem, the OP might not have passed a map instance...

Comment: @NitzanTomer exactly ... The problems was the Object passed to the props was initialised with an empty object, my bad. But should be Typescript be there to warn us from that ?

Comment: The compiler should have error on that.  If you show more of your code we may try and find out why it did not.

Comment: @NitzanTomer see my edit

Comment: Well, you've set `myMap` to be `any` which basically turns off the type checking. If it would have been `myMap: string` then the compiler would have complained

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved; That had nothing to do with a compilation problem, but because wrong object initialisation.